# Rails: Create Multiple Records In A Single Submit using a Multi-Select field

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, forms, multi-select

I have the following form that WORKS:

```
<%= form_for @task do |f| %>
<%= f.error_messages %>
<p>
<%= f.label :name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :name %>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.label :color_id %><br />
<%= f.text_field :color_id %>
</p>
<p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

Here are my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :tasks
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
attr_accessible :name, :user_id, :color_id
end

class Colors < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

What I have been unsuccessful at is changing this

```
<%= f.label :color_id %><br />
<%= f.text_field :color_id %>
```

to a multi select box.

I thought this would be straight forward, but when I try this:

```
<%= f.select(:color_id, [['Red', '1'],
['Blue', '2'],
['Yellow', '3'],
['Green', '4'],
['White', '5']
],{ :prompt => "Please select"},
{ :multiple => true, :size => 5 }
) %>
```

The form looks right, but when submitted it does not matter what is selected (either a singles selection or multiple selections) it always sends the number 1 to the color_id cell in the DB.  If I do not select anything -- the field is blank in the table.

What I want to occur is that it submits the color_ids into the color_id cell BUT adds separate rows for each task and associated color.

So if I use the form and select Red and Blue -- my task table will have two rows and the column that is storing the color_id will have the red id in one row and the blue id in another.

I have also tried using collections and the various relationships (has_many etc.) with no success.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear if you want the result to be two new separate tasks, one Red and one Blue, or one task that associated with two colors: Red and  Blue.

Comment: Is color_id an integer?  It would need to be a string to pass in an array of id's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that you want the result to be one task, for example named 'Foo', that has two colors, Red and Blue, associated with it.

If this is the case, then I think you need to extend your models to be:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :colors
attr_accessible :name, :user_id, :color_id
end

class Colors < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :task
end
```

then remove color_id from your task schema and add task_id to your colors schema.

Then take a look at [Nested Model Form Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) on how to create multiple color values from one form.

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for -- but when I followed the Nested Form Tutorial -- everything seemed to work properly with the form but when I hit submit -- no data was saved to the color model -- only data to the task model.  Also, when I added the code to my  Tasks#index to see what I thought would be empty data I got the following message -- undefined method `colors' for nil:NilClass -- I assume both the no data and the message are related but have double checked my code and have been unable to spot my mistake.  Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: I finally got it to work (submitting the data)  -- I was forgetting to add attr_accessible :name, :user_id, :colors_attributes -- now my only problem is why the Tasks#index is coming up with the error undefined method `colors' for nil:NilClass when I use this code: <ol><% for attitude in @task.colors %><li><%=h color.name %></li><% end %></ol>

Comment: This line actually reads:  Tasks#index is coming up with the error undefined method `colors' for nil:NilClass when I use this code: <ol><% for color in @task.colors %><li><%=h color.name %></li><% end %></ol> -- I had a typo in the above -- but it still spits and error ---

Comment: Need to see your Tasks#index code and apps/view/index.html.erb, but I would guess `@tasks` (plural) is what is being defined in index. If so, you view should iterate over `@tasks` and create a local variable, probably `task` not `@task`

Comment: Not sure why -- which I will have to do a little research on -- but your answer was spot on -- changing it from @task to task worked like a charm -- I greatly appreciate the help --- hopefully it is smooth sailing from here -- but if not maybe I will be lucky enough to have you run across another one of my posts ---

Comment: Steve:  I do have one additional question -- when I use my original multi-select code it enters all the data into the name field of the colors table.  I want there to be one task (which it is) but I want the color table to have separate entries all tied to single task.  The individual fields works this way but no the multi-select.  any suggestion?

Comment: You should probably open another question and post the code for your color and item's create and update actions and the item and color models.

Comment: Steve:  I posted a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250180/rails-need-multi-select-form-to-submit-data-in-seperate-rows -- any assistance would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

User has_many tasks says one user can have multiple tasks, but user you are using stores  multiple tasks in a single query if you want to store like that you should use **accept_nested_attributes_for** method in Active record

accept_nested_attribures_for :tasks