# Rails: Need Multi Select Form To Submit Data in Seperate Rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I currently have the below working properly in my application:

**Form**

```
<%= f.fields_for :types do |builder| %>
<p>
<%= builder.select(:name, [['Type A', 'Type A'],
['Type B', 'Type B'],
['Type C', 'Type C'],
['Type D', 'Type D'],
['Type E', 'Type E']
],{ :prompt => "Please select"},
{ :multiple => true, :size => 5 }
) %>
</p>
% end %>
```

**Controller**

```
def new
@task = Task.new
1.times { @task.types.build }
end
```

**Type Model**

```
class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :task
accepts_nested_attributes_for :task
attr_accessible :name, :task_attributes
end
```

**Task Model**

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :types, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :types
attr_accessible :types_attributes
end
```

My problem is that when submitted the information all goes into the same row and 'name" field in the types table -- I need it to create separate rows in the types table.

I need this solution http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/195729-multiple-select-drop-down-data-saved-to-mysql-how/ but for Rails

I can get separate rows created using text fields with the below code:

**Form**

```
<%= f.fields_for :types do |builder| %>
<p>
<%= builder.label :name, "Type Name" %><br />
<%= builder.text_field :name %>
<%= builder.check_box :_destroy %>
<%= builder.label :_destroy, "Remove Chore" %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

**Controller**

```
def new
@task = Task.new
3.times { @task.types.build }
end
```

Any assistance wold be appreciated.

Comment: Not knowing your models' assocations, my guess is that you want fields_for :types rather than :Type

Comment: The above was a typo (which I have now modified above) but unfortunately -- still same problem -- it submits the data (which is a good thing) to the "type" table with no problem -- but all data is put in the 'name' cell for one row ---  I need separate rows with each row only have one entry in the name field --- this works perfectly if I use individual text fields ---

Comment: Doh! The basic problem is that you can't accomplish what you want using fields for and nested attributes. Try removing that and making the collection select go to type_ids.

Comment: I am still not getting the expected result.  I removed what you said and tried collection sets -- and although I can get the drop down to appear and submit -- now nothing gets sent to the database.

Comment: Not sure if I am doing collection select correct -- can you give me an example of my task controller and view --- i thought i had to use nested attributes or the task form would not submit to the type model

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from a project of mine:

```
class Manuscript < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :readerships
  has_many :editors, :through => :readerships
end

class Readership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :manuscript
  belongs_to :editor
end

class Editor < ActiveRecord::Base
end

= form_for resource do |form|
  = form.collection_select :editor_ids, available_editors, :id, :name, {}, {:multiple => true, :size => 2}
```

Here is the HTML of the above collection_select:

```
<input name="manuscript[editor_ids][]" type="hidden" value="">
<select id="manuscript_editor_ids" multiple="multiple" name="manuscript[editor_ids][]" size="2">
  <option value="3">Dr. Bob Johnson</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="4">John Salamandro</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="1">Erasmus Bielowicz</option>
</select>
```

Comment: David.  I think I am getting closer.  I set up a HMT Relationship -- I have Task (which is like your Manuscript) -- I have Type (which is like your Readership) -- I have Color (which is like your editor)  -- when I place this in the Task form <%= form_for :types do |form| %>
<%= form.collection_select :color_ids, description, :id, :name, {}, {:multiple => true, :size => 2} %>
<% end %> -- I get this error message undefined local variable or method `description' -- I also question where the information will be placed -- does it go into the types table?

Comment: I should add in the color model -- 'description' holds the color names

Comment: I think you need to use :color_ids, :id, :description. The :name just means 'call this method on the model to get me the option text'.

Comment: If I place this into the Task form:  <f.input name="task[color_ids][]" type="hidden" value="">
<select id="color_ids" multiple="multiple" name="task[color_ids][]" size="2"><option value="1">Red</option><option value="2">Blue</option><option value="3">Green</option></select> -- the form submits -- but the data does not register in the DB -- my guess is that it does not know where to go --- I need it to go to the Type table and what I need is to have it register the task_id and color_id as a separate row based on number of items selected --

Comment: So the colors belong to the task or the type? And the attr_accessible or strong parameter is properly set?

Comment: David:  Not sure what the problem is -- have checked and rechecked work -- so I tried to tackle the problem from another direction using a gem -- but now I have come across a different issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20297131/awesome-nested-fields-gem-nested-form-not-showing --- thanks for your help ---